# How to check if an user belongs to several groups in Odoo?

Tags: javascript, odoo-8, odoo

I am trying to perform an action if an user belongs to several groups, in JavaScript.

So I have the following code, which works:

```
Users.call('has_group', ['group1']).done(function(belongs_to_group1) {
    if (belongs_to_group1 == true)
        Users.call('has_group', ['group2']).done(function(belongs_to_group2) {
            if (belongs_to_group2 == true)
                Users.call('has_group', ['group3']).done(function(belongs_to_group3) {
                    if (belongs_to_group3 == true)
                        perform_the_action();
                    else
                        return;
                });
            else
                return;
        });
    else
        return;
});
```

The problem is that it looks awful, and I was wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve this, something like:

```
Users.call('has_group', ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']).done(function(belongs_to_all_groups) { ... }
```

But last line is not working at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that you need to create another method in python file belongs to **res.users** model in which you should check that user belongs to multiple groups or not and then you need to use this customize method in javascript.

I just give you idea how to do this (however given code may not be executable directly)

```
@api.model
def customize_has_groups(self, groups_ext_ids):
    """here groups_ext_ids is a list of groups(external_id may be)"
    if not groups_ext_ids:
        return False
    user = self.env.user
    for group in groups_ext_ids:
        group_id = self.env.ref(group).id
        if group_id in user.groups_id:
            return False
    return True
```

Here this method returns false if any  of the groups are not belongs to users. You may need to update methods behaviour according to your requirement.

And then you can achieve result by single json_rpc call.

```
Users.call('customize_has_groups', ['group1', 'group2', 'group3']).done(function(belongs_to_all_groups) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to achieve that - has_group method expects only one group at the time (and it has to be fully qualified group name with dot), but you can easily write your own method by inheritance to `res_users` by changing a few lines in python like so:

```
@api.noguess
@tools.ormcache('uid', 'groups_ext_id')
def _has_groups(self, cr, uid, groups_ext_id):
    if not isinstance(groups_ext_id, list):
        groups_ext_id = [groups_ext_id]
    for group_ext_id in groups_ext_id:
        assert group_ext_id and '.' in group_ext_id, "External ID must be fully qualified"
        module, ext_id = group_ext_id.split('.')
        cr.execute("""SELECT 1 FROM res_groups_users_rel WHERE uid=%s AND gid IN
                    (SELECT res_id FROM ir_model_data WHERE module=%s AND name=%s)""",
               (uid, module, ext_id))
       if cr.fetchone() == False:
           return False
    return True
```

I hope that method works (didn't check it in action, just modified existing one from https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7a483a85d46a7298b0b3d27efeefbcd2a11772c4/openerp/addons/base/res/res_users.py#L552) - I guess after that your call from last line will be fine.

Comment: thank you @Mariusz! +1 but I think that if I have to implement the functionality because it does not exist yet, it is better not to overwrite an existing method, and create yours just in case.